# In the future can the people behind the law branch of Stack Exchange support HTML tags `<u>...</u>` for underlining?

Tags: feature-request

#### In the future (e.g. next year) would the people behind the law branch of Stack Exchange be willing to support HTML tags `<u>...</u>` for underlining?

An example is shown below:

```
<u>Underline Me</u>
```

[image: A screen capture of underlined text]

---

#### Please note, that Stack Exchange ***Law*** already supports more than a half of a dozen HTML tags; it is not entirely a new idea

#### There is a precedent

#### The work required for adding `<u>...</u>` for underlining could re-use a lot of existing code for the pre-existing HTML tags, rather than requiring new never before seen things

#### There is already code in place for for formatting stricken text, emboldened text, and italicized text with HTML tags.

| Tag | Full English Word | Description | Preview | Example of Source Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `<a>` | Anchor | <sup>Used to create hyperlinks to other webpages.</sup> | [Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) | `<a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com">Stack Exchange</a>` |
| `<b>` | Bold | <sup>Renders your writing in large **bold** letters.</sup> --- <sup>Renders the same as `<strong>`.</sup> | **The Law** | `<b>The Law</b>` |
| `<strong>` | strong | <sup>Indicates that the contents have **strong** importance, seriousness, or urgency. Renders in bold type.</sup> --- <sup>Renders the same as `<b>`.</sup> | **Stack Exchange** | `<strong>Stack Exchange</strong>` |

Answer (score 3):

### Sorry, no

This is a network wide thing and not something we can help with. See [Why can we format text with bold and italic but not underline?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117016/why-can-we-format-text-with-bold-and-italic-but-not-underline)